# How to write an exponential line equation as a formula in Excel

Tags: excel, math, excel-formula

I've plotted a graph and used an exponential trend line to give me an equation.  I'd like to be able to use that equation to forecast based on varying my X value.

How would I express this equation in a formula? y = 3E-38e<sup>0.0023x</sup>

I think that the uppercase E in this case means 3*10^-38

I think the lowercase e refers to the mathematical constant e and is represented in excel using the formula =EXP().

So I've tried  =3*10^-38*EXP(0.0023*x) where x is the cell reference for my value of x, but this produced values that were much too large.

Thanks in advance

Edit:
[an image of the graph I produced](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0g58x.png)

Comment: What would be a sample value for *x* and what are you expecting? (Is this a heat equation?)

Comment: Your assumptions about *Ey* referring to 10^y, and *e^z* being `EXP(z)` are correct, so your formula seems ok.

Comment: try take E-38 out from your formula, its just 10^-38. so instead calculate and draw `y=3*EXP(0.0023x)`. label ur y-axis correctly

Comment: x is a date, but excel treats it as a number so I don't think this should matter the number for the date is 42005.  I'm getting a result for y of 27224.67, when by eye looking at the graph it should be nearer 5800 for that value of x.

Comment: try use a scientific calculator to calc... i think Excel is right

Comment: btw, i wonder what is `x` stands for ? 42005 for 1/1/2015 ? you can't use it that way...

Comment: I think I can use 42005 for a date in this equation.  Excel has no problem using numbers that equate to dates in formulas usually.  I'm not sure I'm following what you're suggesting as a solution though, I'm not saying excel is wrong about anything.  Thanks for your responses though.

Comment: I'll try to explain better why I think the result is wrong - or more like the formula I wrote is wrong - Excel is correct.  Looking at the graph, where x is 42005 (01/01/15), the value for y where the exponential curve is plotted is roughly 4800 (5800 was a typo)

Comment: funny... but try x = 12/07/2012. you will get y approx 4800.

Comment: I've edited the OP to add an image of the graph.  Hopefully that'll better illustrate why I think the result of the formula I created is wrong or rather the formula I created does not represent the one given by the equation on the chart.

Comment: fwiw, if you change the **3** to **5.3** as in `=(5.3*POWER(10, -38))*EXP(0.0023*A1)`, you get results consistent with your graph's results.